# Node.js, Start TCP server using express.js server

Tags: node.js, express, tcp

Can we start the TCP server using the port of express.js server, i know socket.io can do that using the following code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log("server started on port 3000");
});
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: Akram, you're using the term TCP wrong or you mistunderstood something. Because socket.io doesn't use a TCP protocol, it was built to use WebSocket, that is a low-level layer over TCP. And AFAIK express.js uses HTTP protocol for client-server communication.

Comment: Correct, but how could the express share the same port with socket.io?

Comment: From this [article](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/143158/an-introduction-to-websockets/): "The [Websocket] protocol specification makes it clear that one of the design decisions when making this protocol was to ensure that both HTTP based clients and WebSocket based ones can operate on the same port."